# QNetworkAccessManager delete later while requests are added

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have one QNetworkAccessManager to handle all my requests.
The manager can receive an action to send a post request at anytime the application is running.
I noticed there is almost a 70s timeout time before a QNetworkReply finishes when there is no internet.

In the constructor of the class I create the manager with:

```
mgr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
connect(mgr,SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &)),this,SLOT(handleSSLErrors(QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &)));
```

The request are created with:

```
QNetworkReply * reply = mgr->post(request, payload);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, 
SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
```

For the networkreplies I have a signal slot:

```
connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

I delete the QNetworkReply rep in the requestFinished method with `rep->deleteLater();`.

With this I expect all QNetworkReply to be deleted automatically.

In the desctructor of the class I run

```
delete mngr
```

*my thoughts:
0:00 I send a request.
0:01 I delete the mngr (which automatically deletes the onfinished slot)
1:10 the request finishes, there is no longer a slot so deleteLater() is  not called.*

What is the proper way to delete the 'QNetworkAccessManager', It is possible my appliation send a request every 60 seconds that timeouts for 70 seconds (meaning there is always an ongoing request). How can I delete the qnetworkmanager without creating memory leaks?

Comment: Maybe call the class `deleteLater()` in the slot of `requestFinished`?

Comment: @wthung  I have but that does not cover the scenario where the mngr is deleted before the request finishes because at that point the slot does not exist anymore

Comment: Is "0:01 I delete the mngr" necessary? Looks that the class got deleted very quickly but I think the class should be deleted after `requestFinished` slot has been called. Since the class is also a QObject derived class, just call `deleteLater()` in the slot of `requestFinished`

Comment: @wthung Thats just an example of a timeline that would couse the problem. How can I get the reply removed if the slot does not exist. and if the slot still exists the mngr is not removed right?

Comment: Maybe an ugly way to store the pointer to a global one can solve the problem, but I don't recommend this. I recommend keep the class alive until it's not used anymore. In this way you won't suffer from the problem you asked.

Comment: @wthung that means that in the worst case my shutdown will take an extra 70 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connect(mgr, &QNetworkAccessManager::destroyed, reply, &QNetworkReply::deleteLater);
```

QObjects offer the `destroyed()` signal. So you can connect your managers `destroyed()` with the open replys `deleteLater()`. When your manager is destroyed all open replies will be deleted. In case the reply finishes with the manager still alive, you explicitly call the `deleteLater()` as you already do, which will prevent the reply from lingering until you destroy the manager.